# sharepoint interview question, whats wrong with it, or is there a better way to do this0

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

this is like an interview question given to me by someone, can you tell me whats wrong with it or if there is a better way of doing this. this will be run in a large enterprise. NOTE : Demo.Tasks.Task is a custom object whose deninition is not shown in this code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace Demo.WebParts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description for MyTasks.
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultProperty("Text"),
        ToolboxData("<{0}:WebPart1 runat=server></{0}:WebPart1>"),
        XmlRoot(Namespace="Demo.Tasks")]
    public class MyTasks : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        private const string defaultListName = "";
        private string listName = defaultListName;
        private ArrayList alTasks;

        [Browsable(true),
            Category("Miscellaneous"),
            DefaultValue(defaultListName),
            WebPartStorage(Storage.None),
            FriendlyName("List Name Filter"),
            Description("The name of sps lists to gather tasks from")]
        public string ListName
        {
            get
            {
                return listName;
            }

            set
            {
                listName = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            alTasks = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                SPWeb myWeb = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
                foreach(SPList list in myWeb.Lists)
                {
                    if(list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
                    {
                        if(list.Title == listName)
                        {
                            getTasksFromList(list);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach(SPWeb subWeb in myWeb.Webs)
                    foreach(SPList list in subWeb.Lists)
                        if(list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
                            getTasksFromList(list);
            }
            catch
            {}
        }

        private void getTasksFromList(SPList list)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<list.ItemCount;i++)
            {
                if(list.Items[i]["AssignedTo"].ToString() == this.Context.User.Identity.Name)
                {
                    Demo.Tasks.Task tsk = Tasks.Task.CreateTask();
                    tsk.Title = list.Items[i]["Title"].ToString();
                    tsk.DueDate = (DateTime)list.Items[i]["DueDate"];
                    tsk.Description = list.Items[i]["Description"].ToString();
                    tsk.Priority = (int)list.Items[i]["Priority"];
                    alTasks.Add(tsk);

                    //now update the item
                    list.Items[i]["LastViewed"] = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render this Web Part to the output parameter specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="output"> The HTML writer to write out to </param>
        protected override void RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            try
            {
                string strHTML = "";
                for(int i=0;i<alTasks.Count;i++)
                {
                    Demo.Tasks.Task tsk = (Demo.Tasks.Task)alTasks[i];
                    strHTML = strHTML + "The task " + tsk.Title + " is due on " + tsk.DueDate + "<BR>" + tsk.Description + "<BR><BR>";
                }
                output.Write(strHTML);
            }
            catch
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you'll give us more info (what doesn't work, etc.).

But in my opinion you should use 'using' when you're working with SPWeb or SPSite. Not doing this sometimes causes strange errors:

```
using (SPWeb myWeb = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context))
{
    foreach (SPList list in myWeb.Lists)
    {
        if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
        {
            if (list.Title == listName)
                getTasksFromList(list);
        }
    }
}

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
{
    foreach (SPWeb subWeb in site.AllWebs)
    {
        try //should be 1st statement after foreach
        {
            foreach (SPList list in subWeb.Lists)
            {
                if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
                    getTasksFromList(list);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (subWeb != null)
                subWeb.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can read about this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2009/01/14/try-finally-using-sharepoint-dispose.aspx